# QueryBuilder for MongoDB dosen't work in Symfony

Tags: mongodb, symfony

I have in Repository class one function for select from database.

```
/**
 * My function.
 *
 * @param integer $param1
 * @param integer $param2
 * @param integer $param3
 * @return Response
 */
public function getData($param1, $param2, $param3)
{
    $qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
        ->select('param_1', 'param_2', 'param_3');

    $query = $qb->getQuery();
    $result = $query->execute();

    return new Response(json_encode($result),200);
}
```

But the result is empty?
What's wrong in my code?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with this:

```
$qb = $this->createQueryBuilder()
    ->hydrate(false)
    ->select('param_1', 'param_2', 'param_3');

$query = $qb->getQuery();
$result = $query->execute()->toArray();
```

Comment: I tried but it's a limit of 6-7 minutes for waited before validate the answer. :))

Answer (score 0):

try replacing execute() get getArrayResult()

Comment: Method not found.